# How to get alert when a message in delivered in window form application?

Tags: winforms

```
private void buttonSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InsertChatDetails();
    //textBoxChat.Text += System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + "" + System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Computername") + Environment.NewLine;
    textBoxChat.Text += textBoxMessage.Text + Environment.NewLine;
    textBoxMessage.Text = "";
}

public void InsertChatDetails()                                                     //Inserting Values
{
    try
    {
        CommonCS CommonSample1 = new CommonCS();
        BusinessCS BFSample1 = new BusinessCS();

        CommonSample1.Id = "1";
        CommonSample1.FromUser = textBoxChat.Text += System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + "-->" + Program.UserName + Environment.NewLine;
        //CommonSample1.FromUser = textBoxChat.Text += System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + "" + System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Computername") + Environment.NewLine;
        CommonSample1.ToUser = "";
        CommonSample1.MessageText = textBoxMessage.Text;
        CommonSample1.SentOn = DateTime.Now;
        CommonSample1.StatusReport = 0;
        BFSample1.InsertChatDetails(CommonSample1);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to get a notification message wen a message is passed...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure from your code what you are trying to do, but if its synchronous you can trace it after `SendMessageToWinMachine()` ,else you can use `CallBack` Method for asynchronus call.